# Inserting delays using curl for url unshortening

Tags: linux, url, curl, xargs

I am using the following script to unshorten urls in my file : shortened_urls.txt

> cat shortened_urls.txt | xargs -n 1 curl -x 23.100.73.22
>   samemon:PasSworD@myprivateproxy.net:15213 -Ls -I -o /dev/null -w
>   %{url_effective}'\n' > unshortened.txt & wait

Now my file shortened_urls.txt contains say 4000 urls. How can I insert some waits of say 1 second after each url is unshortened.

Comment: See the Bash `sleep` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl -x 23.100.73.22 samemon:PasSworD@myprivateproxy.net:15213 -Ls -I -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective}'\n' $1 >> unshortened.txt; sleep 1
```

Put this part to `resolve-url.sh`

And invoke cat shortened_urls.txt | xargs -n 1 sh ./resolve-url.sh

Comment: I get the following : 
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
curl: no URL specified!

Comment: @ShahanAliMemon oh, I've fixed the text, you should add $1 for curl to see.